# How to search street by name, and highlight / change the road color?

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, choropleth

I have a question that may be basic, but I found the answer in the plugin documentation.

I'm using the http://leafletjs.com/ plugin based on https://www.openstreetmap.org maps, and I wonder how can I do to highlight / select / focus on a street, using her name for the search?

The idea is to change the road color, according to the number of traffic accidents for example;
 But only have the name of the street as a basis, not the geographical coordinates;

I have in the database the names of the streets, and the amount of accidents, the idea is to use this information to display on a map the streets with most cases showing the streets with color green (less cases) to red (most cases ).

Anyone know how I can do this? there is a plugin that facilitates / allow highlight an entire street, searching by name?

Of course I do not expect someone give me the code ready, I would like a "North", I wonder if it is possible, and who knows where I can find an example, a documentation ...

[image]

I added an example, an image to be more easily identified What do I want.
  This image I got using openstreetmap site. When you search for a street name, the system shows the return options, and when you click on them, it marks the street with a line extension. Just like in the picture.

Thank you so much

Comment: So you need to obtain the raw road data based on a name and rough location. Take a look at [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API).

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the colour of the basemap (it's a set of .png/.jpg images). You'll need to have some *vector* data for the roads, and use `L.Polyline` to display them with the colours you want.

Where to get vector data for the roads is a different issue. OSM dumps, OSM Overpass, or regional government/transportation authorities are good points to start.

Comment: I added an image in question.